# undefined method `discussion_postcomments_path' for #<#<Class:0x7a1c360>:0x7a20c38>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently added a new Model (discussion.rb) and Controller (discussions_controller.rb). I am trying to get postcomments to work with discussions.

discussion.rb

```
class Discussion < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :postcomments, dependent: :destroy
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true

  attr_accessible :content, :user_id

  default_scope order: 'discussions.created_at DESC'
end
```

Here's what I have in routes

```
resources :discussions, :path => "disc"

resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :discussions, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :microposts do
  resources :postcomments
  resources :discussions do
    resources :postcomments
  end
end
```

here's the postcomments model

```
class Postcomment < ActiveRecord::Base


  attr_accessible :comment_content

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :micropost
  belongs_to :discussion

  validates :comment_content, presence: true
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  default_scope order: 'postcomments.created_at ASC'
end
```

I'm trying to use this in view except, I get the error posted in the title

```
<%= form_for([discussion, @comment]) do |f| %>
<%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :comment_content %>
  </div>
  <div class="ItemContainer">
<div class="ItemInput">
    <button class="btn" type="submit">
    Comment
  </button>
  </div><div class="ItemCommentCount">
<% end %>
```

It says that the error is caused from this line

```
 <%= form_for([discussion, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

Anyone know how I can fix this `path` problem?

```
class PostcommentsController < ApplicationController
def create
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comment = Postcomment.new(params[:postcomment])
    @comment.micropost = @micropost
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render partial: 'shared/_postcomment_form', locals: { micropost: @micropost }
    end
  end

def createdisc
    @discussion = Discussion.find(params[:discussion_id])
    @comment = Postcomment.new(params[:postcomment])
    @comment.discussion = @discussion
    @comment.user = current_user
    if @comment.save
       redirect_to(:back)
    else
      render partial: 'shared/_postcomment_form', locals: { discussion: @discussion}
    end
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try consolidating your use of `resources :discussions` in your routes file. I've edited below assuming you didn't intend to nest discussions under microposts.

```
resources :discussions, only: [:create, :destroy], path: "disc" do
  resources :postcomments
end
resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
resources :microposts, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :relationships, only: [:create, :destroy]
resources :microposts do
  resources :postcomments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
<%= form_for([discussion, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

This `discussion` should be an instance variable as well:

```
<%= form_for([@discussion, @comment]) do |f| %>
```

Then you need to define @discussion in the controller

Comment: any idea based on the codes I posted above how I can get the postcomment to associate itself to a discussion and not a discussion? I'm trying to use postcomment for BOTH. Here's the error I'm getting `Couldn't find Micropost without an ID`, `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PostcommentsController#create`. I just posted up the PostcommentsController

Comment: I meant to say, associate itself to a discussion, and not the micropost. I can postcomment to micropost, but I can't seem to do it to a discussion